# Avoiding Microsoft Edge "isn't commonly downloaded" warning

Tags: security, browsers

I have shifted software downloads for our customers to download from our domain instead of Dropbox. Now Microsoft Edge raises the "isn't commonly downloaded" warning. I had this on Chrome too but resolved it by adding our domain to Google Search Console, now there is no warning in Chrome.

I have imported our domain property from Google Search Console into Microsoft Bing Webmaster Tools, but the warning in Microsoft Edge persists.

[image]

I'm aware of EV code-signing but that is a large exercise for the dozens of bespoke applications we distribute and I need to find a large chunk of engineering capacity to work that into our build pipeline.

Meanwhile, what other steps can I take to remove this warning?